# Binary addition carry and overflow in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build a function that calculates the checksum of four elements in an 8-bit array. What I am struggling with is the carry and overflow of binary addition. For example:

```
    101
    +
    101
    ----
   1010
```

it overflows we wraparound the most left with the most right so it becomes 011.

I am able to do the calculation using **bin**. I can do the above if the right most value is 0 and the left most value is 1 because in that case we won't have to carry anything to the next value from the right.

**What I am struggling with is, something like this scenario:**

```
    111
    +
    110
    ----
   1101
```

it overflows again but this time we have to wraparound ***1(left most)+1(right most) = 10*** which means we will take **0** and carry **1** to the next right most **(0)** in this case. The final result in that case would be = **110**

if it was **1** instead of **0** we will get **10** again and we will have to carry 1 to the next value and so on and so forth.

See my code below:

```
def overFlow(sumN):  
  # this works if my left most is 1 and my right most is 0
  if(sumN[8] == "0"):
    print("--------------------")
    overflow = bin(int(sumN[0],2) + int(sumN[8],2))[2:]
    temp = list(sumN)
    temp.pop(0)
    temp.pop(7)
    temp.append(overflow)
    newtemp= ""
    for i in temp:
      newtemp += i  
    sumN = newtemp
    print(sumN)
    print("--------------------")
  # else:
  # this is where I am stuck

  return sumN

def checksum(message):
  var1 = message[0][2:]
  var2 = message[1][2:]
  var3 = message[2][2:]
  var4 = message[3][2:]
  bit_len = 8
  print(len(var1))

  sum1 = bin(int(var1,2) + int(var2,2))[2:]
  if(len(sum1) > bit_len):
    sum1 = overFlow(sum1)
  print("var 1  " +var1+"\nvar 2  "+var2+"\nSum    "+sum1)
  sum2 = bin(int(sum1,2) + int(var3,2))[2:]
  if(len(sum2) > bit_len):
    sum2 = overFlow(sum2)
  print("var 1  " +sum1+"\nvar 2  "+var3+"\nSum    "+sum2)
  sum3 = bin(int(sum2,2) + int(var4,2))[2:]
  if(len(sum3) > bit_len):
    sum3 = overFlow(sum3)
  print("var 1  " +sum2+"\nvar 2  "+var4+"\nSum    "+sum3)
  comp = ""
  tot_sum = sum3
  n = len(tot_sum)
  for i in range(n):
    if (tot_sum[i]== '0'):
      comp+= '1';
    if (tot_sum[i]== '1'):
      comp+= '0';
  
  print(f"1's complement is = {comp}")

message = ['0b10110110','0b11011100','0b01100111','0b01111101']
checksum(message);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE:
The right output for the message above should be as follow:

```
var1  10110110
var2  11011100
sum1 110010010 "overflow so we take left most and add it with right most" 1+0 = 1
sum1 becomes = 10010011

sum1  10010011
var3  01100111
sum3  11111010 "no overflow, so we do nothing"

sum3  11111010
var4  01111101
     101110111 "overflow left most(1) + right most (1) = 10" we take zero and carry one to the next right most number
        which is 1 which will give me again 10 so we take zero and carry one until we don't have to carry anymore
the final result should be **01110000** 
after 1's compelement it should be **10001111**
```

and this is my current output:

```
var 1  10110110
var 2  11011100
Sum    10010011
var 1  10010011
var 2  01100111
Sum    11111010
var 1  11111010
var 2  01111101
Sum    101110111
1's complement or the checksum is = 010001000
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: You have the code already.  Trace the execution (generally done with strategically-placed `print` statements).  Where does your wrap-around code differ from what you expect?

Comment: just cut the number with the overflow into 2 numbers, 1 is 1 char (overflow) and other is 8 chars, and treat these the same as you do for the 2 8-character binary numbers. Repeat this wraparound till you don't have an overflow

Comment: remove the semicolons, for ones-complement use `string.translate`

Comment: in 18 lines of code the result is `1's complement is = 0000111`

Comment: @Prune I have updated my question with MRE. Please have a look at it

Comment: @rioV8 I actually did try to do something like that but it gets messy. I thought maybe there's a pythonic way to do this.

Comment: Bit banging (or any other low level function) is not really Python's forte.  Shifts/Rotates/checksums/etc. is often done in C or Assembler.  You can do those things in Python, but it often gets a bit messy.  That being said, your wraparound bit won't cause another wraparound overflow, because that would mean your prior addition was all 1's and a wraparound 1, which can't happen.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am doing this for a project and I have to use Python. To your point, my issue is with wraparound 1+1=10, take 0 carry 1 if the next element is 1 then again 10, take 0 carry 1 until you don't carry anymore by hitting a 1+0 = 1. I don't know how to think about this one. I thought there's maybe a shorter way to do that so I asked.

Comment: Binary math is just math.  Python can do math.  I'll post an answer that should do what you describe.

Comment: Do you really need to show this entire process and manipulate the bits as bits? Or do you only have to get the correct answer? Because there is a much simpler way if you just get the corresponding integer values for the bit-strings.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I need to show the output as I shared above without my comments about overflow that's just for clarity.

Comment: Then you can do the addition (and overflow logic) with normal integers, and convert back to binary for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple 8-bit checksum routine, with rollover.  There is a wrapper function that accepts and returns data in the original ascii binary format.  But you really just want to work with bin array and the first function.

```
def checksum(bin_array):
    result = 0
    for num in bin_array:
        result += num
        if result >= 256:
            result -=255 # subtract 256 and add one
        # print(bin(result)) # show partial result if desired
    return result

def checksum_binstrs(ascii_bin_array):
    bin_array = list(map(lambda x: int(x,2),ascii_bin_array)) # convert to binary array
    result = checksum(bin_array)
    return bin(result) # convert to binary string


message = ['0b10110110','0b11011100','0b01100111','0b01111101']

print (checksum_binstrs(message))
```

Comment: ah I feel so terrible looking at my code. I see how you approached this, I didn't think of it that way. Thank you for your time.